# Can we target a element which has (data-toggle="collapse") attribute and no class using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can we target a element which has (data-toggle="collapse") attribute and no class using jquery?

`<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#list1" class="" aria-expanded="true"></li>`

Comment: [Attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle=\"collapse\"]")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jquery:

```
$('*[data-toggle="collapse"]');
```

Without jquery:

```
document.querySelector("[data-toggle=\"collapse\"]") // It will select only one element (the first, if several)
document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle=\"collapse\"]") // It will select all elements with the class
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
$('[data-toggle=collapse]')
```

In case you need to see some documentation, [here's the link](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).